# the top of the page from iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

is there any way how to make link inside iframe to control main page. I need to make a link from iframe that makes main page go to the top.

For example

```
<html> <- mainpage
  ...some arcticle...
  <iframe>
    ...long article...
    <a href="goback">Go Back</a>
  </iframe>
</html>
```

After clicked to "Go Back" I need to scroll to the top of main page (not just iframe)

I can't use "back to the top" link inside mainpage, it has to be in iframe.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

You can jump to the top of a page by using the `id` attribute in elements.

```
<html id="top">
    <!-- Some content here -->
    <iframe>
        <!-- Long Article here -->
        <a href="#top">Jump to top</a>
    </iframe>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

This cannot be done within iframe. You cannot control the iframe from parent page and vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

Your link inside the iframe should be the following

```
<a href="http://full-address-of-the-parent-page/#top" target="_parent">go back</a>
```

Important factors are the `_parent` value of the `target` attribute and that the `href` contains the full URL of the parent page, otherwise the browser will redirect the parent page to the framed document's URL (+ anchor). Not sure if every browser does the jump only or there will be full page reload, though.

If both documents are of the same origin (see JavaScript's same-origin policy), then it could also be done via script, e.g.

```
window.parent.scrollTo(0, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it works!

```js
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script>
   $(document).ready(function () {
       $(window).scroll(function () {
           if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
               $('.scrollup').fadeIn();
           } else {
               $('.scrollup').fadeOut();
           }
       });
       $('.scrollup').click(function () {
           $("html, body").animate({
               scrollTop: 0
           }, 600);
           return false;
       });
   });
 </script>
```